# complete the sequence sort values based on column values

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

given: [demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/76f9a/2)

```
OneTable
Id,GroupId,TopId,TopSort
-------------------------
1,1,101,2
2,1,101,2
3,1,102,1
4,1,102,1
5,1,103,null
6,1,103,null
7,1,104,null
8,1,104,null
```

What's best way to complete existing sequence for null values in TopSort column? And if all TopSort values are null, then start sequence based on Id column ascending.

For example,

Above should look like the following:

```
OneTable
Id,GroupId,TopId,TopSort
-------------------------
1,1,101,2
2,1,101,2
3,1,102,1
4,1,102,1
5,1,103,3
6,1,103,3
7,1,104,4
8,1,104,4
```

Bonus:
Can the same SQL work if all TopSort values were null to begin with?

Just looking for hints and not answers only.

Comment: Please explain what "*re-sequence*" means in your case.

Comment: let me rephrase by saying complete the sequence, and if all null sequence based on Id. I'll change the subject.

Comment: What sequence and how do you want to complete it?

Comment: It appears from your example you simply want `ORDER BY TopID, ID` If this is incorrect please provide another example

Comment: I suggest step-by-step explanation of your table transformation.

Comment: What about a WHERE clause with "IS NOT NULL" to ignore NULL values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to take the existing top sort values and then update the values.  I think you can do this:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by TopSort order by TopId) as seqnum,
             max(case when TopSort is not null then TopSort end) over () as maxts
      from tracker t
     )
update toupdate
    set TopId = coalesce(maxts, 0) + seqnum
    where TopId is Null;
```

This may be a bit hard to follow.  The variable `seqnum` assigns a sequential number to the rows based on TopId.  The values when `TopSort` is NULL start at 1 and continue from there.  And those are the only values that will be used.

The column `maxts` gets the maximum value for the `TopSort` variable in the data.  This is the base for the assignment.

Finally, the value you want is the sum of the sequence number and the maximum top sort value.